# Outputting keys and values of dict of dicts to a list as strings x-times depending on an int value

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I am outputting the keys and values of a dict of dicts into a list for evaluation purposes.

An example dictionary looks like this:

```
gold_network = {'Anakin': {'All Jedi': {'fear': 1},
                        'Jedi': {'fear': 4},
                        'Mace': {'anticipation': 1, 'fear': 1},
                        'Obi-Wan': {'joy': 2, 'surprise': 2},
                        'Qui-Gon': {'fear': 2,
                                    'joy': 1,
                                    'sadness': 4,
                                    'surprise': 3,
                                    'trust': 5},
                        'The Council': {'anticipation': 1, 'fear': 1},
                        'Yoda': {'anticipation': 1, 'surprise': 1},
                        'young boy': {'sadness': 3, 'trust': 1}},
             'Jedi': {'Anakin': {'joy': 2}},
             'Obi-Wan': {'Anakin': {'joy': 2, 'trust': 2}},
             'Qui-Gon': {'Anakin': {'anger': 2, 'joy': 2, 'trust': 1}},
             'Yoda': {'Anakin': {'joy': 3}},
             'young boy': {'Anakin': {'joy': 2, 'trust': 3}}}
```

My code to do so looks like this:

```
gold_list_complete = list('{}-{}-{}'.format(k, k1, k2) for k, v in\
                          gold_network.items() for k1,v1 in v.items()\
                          for k2 in v1.keys())
```

The wished output looks fine, e.g.: `[Anakin-All Jedi-fear,...]`

But I would like to be able to output that format as many times as the last `int`-value of the last dict.

E.g. for the relation `Anakin-Jedi-fear` where the `int` is a `4`:
`[Anakin-Jedi-fear, Anakin-Jedi-fear, Anakin-Jedi-fear, Anakin-Jedi-fear, ...#other relations]` would be the desired output to the list of that relation.

I tried multiplying the whole line of code but it gives me the error message, that the value is not defined.

Any ideas on what to add to the code to output the relation as its last `int` value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, instead of `for k2 in v1.keys()` you could do `for k2,v2 in v2.items()` and repeat that for `v2` times.

```
list('{}-{}-{}'.format(k, k1, k2)
     for k, v in gold_network.items()
     for k1,v1 in v.items()
     for k2,v2 in v1.items()
     for _ in range(v2))
```